# create database /tables/ procedures on procedure call

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I wanted to create database including all it's tables and stored procedures at the time of calling stored procedure from another database. so how can we do this?

any help would be appreciated
thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use linked server for  same. Once you have linked server  , you can use four part naming convention to identify object.

For part naming convention = server.database.schema.object

Comment: thnx for reply
i have already tried linked server concept. but its works only for tables not for stored procedure. means using linked server concept tables are created in new created database bt procedures are not created.